# How to properly create the SQL query for displaying number of products in each refined criteria of the specified results

Tags: php, mysql, product

I'm building a page for displaying the results of a specified search within a table of products. 
What I want to achieve is to display a "Filter widget", to allow users to refine their search. In this widget I want to display a set of available options, along with the number of results in those options. So effectively users would see how many results they will get if they choose to refine their search to each criteria. This would require searching within the original search results.
An example of this can be sen [here](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E3606&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=detachedshouses),  where "Filter your results" side bar, a set of refined searches are displayed along with the number of properties in parentheses.

I was wondering if there is any proper way to handle this issue, and get the number of the refined searches in the original SQL query, rather than create a separate query for each refined criteria.

Comment: You would have to save the first query results in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer Re-formed after some more thought

The original answer will work, but as you noted it will run the original search query multiple times and consume a large amount of time to process.  An Alternative method that will produce the same result, may be much faster and easier to code.  The answer is hinted at by @JEES among the other answers on this page:

```
SELECT keywords.tag as Tag, COUNT( * ) as ResultCount
FROM keywords CROSS JOIN ( /* search query */ ) as rslt
WHERE
   /* provide the list of rules that will cause the system to eliminate bad row pairings */
GROUP BY Tag
ORDER BY ResultCount
```

This method requires that you define your preferred search tags first in a simple table of just one column.  The CROSS JOIN causes the search results to be repeated over and over again in a new table. For example, considering the following two tables, where each value represents a row with columns (i.e. Result1 might contain 4 columns in a music album search ["artist", "album name", "release year", "album id"] and Result2 will have the same data structure:

Keywords:

```
TagOne, TagTwo

SearchResults: Result1, Result2, Result3, Result4
```

CROSS JOIN causes the following to be produced within the system's working memory:

```
CROSS JOIN TABLE:

TagOne, Result1
TagOne, Result2
TagOne, Result3
TagOne, Result4
TagTwo, Result1
TagTwo, Result2
TagTwo, Result3
TagTwo, Result4
```

The WHERE clause then tells the system which rows to keep and which to discard.  This is where you match the search term to a future result that would be found if that search term were used.  In this case, let's assume that the search term "TagOne" will find Result1, and Result4 but not Result2 and Result3, and "TagTwo" finds all the search results except Result3.

The resulting table in the systems working memory now looks as follows:

```
CROSS JOIN TABLE AFTER WHERE CLAUSE:

TagOne, Result1
TagOne, Result4
TagTwo, Result1
TagTwo, Result2
TagTwo, Result4
```

The count and group by commands work together to reduce this table to the following:

```
CROSS JOIN TABLE AFTER COUNT:

TagOne, 2
TagTwo, 3
```

Then choosing either ASC or DESC will sort these search terms into an order that you find most useful by the search terms.  It is my prediction that this will produce results more quickly than the 2+ sec of the original suggestion.

### Original Answer

The answer to your question is, "Yes, it is possible."  Use PHP to construct your queries one term at a time, and then use UNION to join them into a single expression prior to sending them to your database.

```
SELECT 'searchtag' as Tag, COUNT( * )  as ResultCount
FROM /* current_search_results */ as rslt 
WHERE /* filter_list_here */ GROUP BY Tag 

UNION


SELECT 'searchtag2' as Tag, COUNT( * )  as ResultCount
FROM /* current_search_results */ as rslt 
WHERE /* filter_list_here */ GROUP BY Tag 

UNION


SELECT 'searchtag3' as Tag, COUNT( * ) as ResultCount
FROM /* current_search_results */ as rslt 
WHERE /* filter_list_here */ GROUP BY Tag
```

Replace /* current_search_results */ with a copy of the original search SQL in parenthesis `()` or a reference to a temporary table that was stored on a previous query.  Personally, I like to use the subquery format `()` only because I can worry less when I am not referencing a temporary table that might have been altered/overwritten by another user doing the same query.

The resulting output will be a table that looks like this:

```
Tag  /  ResultCount
searchtag / 500
searchtag2 / 34
searchtag3 / 234
```

Naturally, you can add

```
SELECT * FROM (/*above_query_here*/) as unordered_results ORDER BY ResultCount
```

In order to make the results sorted by search tags that will produce the most records / least records.  Use `ASC` or `DESC` at the end of the `ORDER BY` statement to change the sort order.

Comment: Thanks!!, it really helped in clearing the issue. I tried to use this method, however the resulting SQL is very slow ( it takes about 2.5 seconds to execute). I expect it be this way, since it runs many sql commands within one command. I'm guessing that most of this time is due to recreating the original results in the /* current_search_results */ section of each union statement. Is there a more efficient way to execute this query? perhaps recreate the original results once, and then use that to perform additional operations?

Comment: @Hamid I gave your problem some more thought over the weekend after looking at the solution proposed by JEES.  It might be faster to use JEES's suggestion of making a temporary table of just the keywords.  Then you can join the keyword table and your result table, and perform the count operation on the final result set. The system will generate the same number of results, however, it will run your initial search query only once and then repeat the results in the table once for each search term that you list in your temporary table.  The resulting code will also look much more clean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of the `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(kywds)`, Like this:

[**SQL-Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a76c4/6/0)

```
   SELECT kywds, COUNT(kywds) AS `Results`
     FROM keywords
 GROUP BY kywds
 ORDER BY COUNT(kywds)
```

Where kywds is the column that contains the keywords of the refining filters